# Can I have two different MX records with one domain

Tags: domain, g-suite, mx-record

can I have MX records of two different provider for one domain ?
Like now I've Google Apps MX records set up on my domain control panel. What If I add ZOHO MX records as well as Google's ? would the mail get delivered in two places ? However I can send mail using both

### Edit

It seems it hits the lowest priority (labeled as MX PREF) one. and if that **FAILS** it tries with other one. previously `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.` had `1` and `mx.zohomail.com.` had `2` and No mail was getting delivered to Zoho. Now I made `Google` 6 all mails are delivered to Zoho. Nothing goes to Google

Can I make it deliver both ?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** in response to your edit: no, you can't.  For more details, read on...

MX records are designed so that you can have several; they contain weights as well as hosts, as this example shows:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig mx mathworks.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mathworks.com.      10800   IN  MX  15 mxin3.mathworks.com.
mathworks.com.      10800   IN  MX  10 mxin1.mathworks.com.
mathworks.com.      10800   IN  MX  20 smtp.mathworks.co.uk.
```

The weight is the number after the `MX` and before the hostname.  A well-behaved sending MTA will try the lowest weight one first, then fall back to higher weight servers if the lower ones can't be reached.

What those various servers do with the mail is up to them and their admins.  In the old days, the higher-weight ones were usually just queueing servers; they only received deliveries if the main (low-weight) server was down, and held them in queue until the lowest-weight one came back up, at which time all queued messages were delivered in a burst.  This interferes with some kinds of spam-filtering, and I think is not as common as it used to be.

If you have some kind of shared-storage back-end, then you can use multiple same-weight MX records to have mail delivered to the back-end storage via multiple front-end relays, for redundancy.

So it's really up to you.  But **however many servers you have, and whatever weights they have, a sending MTA should deliver any given message to only one of them; once it's been received by a valid server, it should be deleted from sender's queue, and that's it.**

Answer (score 3):

> can I have MX records of two different provider for one domain ?

of course you can

> would the mail get delivered in two places ?

no, it wouldn't. The mail would be delivered to MX with lowest priority value.

```
@ in MX 10 mail1.example.net.
@ in MX 20 mail2.example.net.
```

With such configuration the first delivery attempt would be to the mail1.example.net and if the host is not responded (connection timeout) then mta will try deliver mail to mail2.example.net

> However I can send mail using both

yes, you can